# When solving systems of linear equations, what happens if you leave the variables in the matrix you're reducing?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

For example, let's say we have $-2x+y+z=5$, $2x+2y=4$, and $3y+4z=2$

We want to solve

$$        \begin{bmatrix}
        -2 & 1 & 1\\
        2 & 2 & 0\\
        0 & 3 & 4\\
        \end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y \\
z
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
5 \\
4\\
2
\end{bmatrix}
$$

To find $x, y$ and $z$ we'd put the following augmented matrix into reduced row echelon form:

\begin{bmatrix}
-2 & 1 & 1 &5 \\
2 & 2 & 0 &4\\
0 & 3 & 4&2
\end{bmatrix}

And then read off the values of $x, y$ and $z$

But what if instead we left the $x, y, z$ vector in the augmented matrix (instead of essentially invisibly multiplying it with matrix $A$)? i.e. what if we put this matrix into RREF:

\begin{equation*}
A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
-2 & 1 & 1 &x \\
2 & 2 & 0 &y\\
0 & 3 & 4&z
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

Doing so results in the matrix

\begin{equation*}
A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & \frac y2 - \frac{x+y}3 + \frac{z-x-y}9 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & \frac{x+y}3 - \frac{z-x-y}9 \\
0 & 0 & 1& \frac{z-x-y}3
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

Do those expressions in the $4$th column involving $x, y$ and $z$ have any significance?

Answer (score 1):

Well, this just means you are letting $\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z\end{bmatrix}$ play the role of $\begin{bmatrix}5 \\ 4 \\ 2\end{bmatrix}$.  So, you are solving for solutions to $$\begin{bmatrix}
        -2 & 1 & 1\\
        2 & 2 & 0\\
        0 & 3 & 4\\
        \end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
a \\
b \\
c
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y\\
z
\end{bmatrix}$$ where you are thinking of $x,y,$ and $z$ as constants and $a,b,$ and $c$ as the variables to solve for.  The solution you found is just the general expression for $a,b,$ and $c$ in terms of $x,y,$ and $z$.

(This is essentially equivalent to inverting the matrix $B=\begin{bmatrix}
        -2 & 1 & 1\\
        2 & 2 & 0\\
        0 & 3 & 4\\
        \end{bmatrix} $, the solution to $B\begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \\ c\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z\end{bmatrix}$ is just $\begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \\ c\end{bmatrix}=B^{-1}\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z\end{bmatrix}$, by multiplying both sides by $B^{-1}$ on the left.)